# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventEmitter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building a ReactJS Weather app where I have a drop-down list with different cities and a container with the information about weather on the selected city. When i fetch the weather data from an API i have a default city and I want to refetch the data when user selects another city in the dropdown list.

I will provide you with the code.

App.jsx class (the main class)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./sass/app.scss";
import axios from "axios";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import NavigationBar from "./components/NavigationBar";
import WeatherComponent from "./components/WeatherComponent";

import { locationOptions } from "./locations.js";

const WEATHER_KEY = "5f0f0f2a61c0f3f650984fb442f03d86";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cityName: "Pristina",
      isLoading: true,
      isSelectedLocationOpen: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { cityName } = this.state;
    const { eventEmitter } = this.props;

    const URL = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${WEATHER_KEY}&query=${cityName}`;
    axios
      .get(URL)
      .then(res => {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          name: data.location.name,
          country: data.location.country,
          temperature: data.current.temperature,
          weather_descriptions: data.current.weather_descriptions[0],
          weather_icons: data.current.weather_icons[0],
          observation_time: data.current.observation_time
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error("Cannot fetch weatcher from API", err);
      });

    eventEmitter.on("updateLocation", data => {
      this.setState({ cityName: data });
    });
  }

  handleChange() {
    const { eventEmitter } = this.props;
    const { cityName } = this.state;
    eventEmitter.emit("updateLocation", cityName);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isLoading,
      name,
      temperature,
      weather_descriptions,
      weather_icons,
      observation_time,
      country
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="first-container">
          <div className="wrapper">
            {isLoading && <h3>Loading ...</h3>}
            <NavigationBar />
            {!isLoading && (
              <WeatherComponent
                className="weather-container"
                name={name}
                temperature={temperature}
                weather_descriptions={weather_descriptions}
                weather_icons={weather_icons}
                observation_time={observation_time}
                country={country}
              />
            )}
            <Dropdown
              placeholder="Select location"
              search
              selection
              defaultValue={this.state.cityName}
              options={locationOptions.map(item => {
                return {
                  key: item.key,
                  value: item.value,
                  text: item.text
                };
              })}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={locationOptions.value}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

store.js class

```
import React from "react";

import { EventEmitter } from "events";

export default class Store extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    // Main App State
    this.state = {
      appName: "Weather App"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        ...this.state,
        eventEmitter: this.eventEmitter
      });
    });
  }
}
```

WeatherComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../sass/weather.scss";
import sunnyIcon from "../assets/sunnyicon.png";
import sun from "../assets/sunicon.png";

export default class WeatherComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  // weather_descriptions i have to find a better icon for current weather

  render() {
    const {
      temperature,
      weather_descriptions,
      observation_time,
      name,
      country
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="weather-container">
        <div className="location-container">
          <img src={sunnyIcon} className="logo2" alt="" />
          <h1 className="total-weather-report">Today's weather report</h1>
          <h1 className="location">{`${name}, ${country}`}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="degree-container">
          <img src={sunnyIcon} className="weather-logo2" alt="" />
          <h2 className="degree-value">{`${temperature}°C`}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="info-container">
          <h2 className="local-weather-report">Local Weather Report</h2>
          <div className="hr"></div>
          <img src={sun} className="sun-icon" alt="" />
          <h2 className="day">Sunday</h2>
          <h2 className="weather-type">{weather_descriptions}</h2>
          <h2 className="last-observation">Last observed on:</h2>
          <h2 className="observation-time">{observation_time}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="weekly-weather"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the app everything works but when I try to change the city from the dropdown, it crashes and this error pops-up.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIYrt.jpg)

Comment: the error happen from which file?

Comment: App.jsx and it says that eventEmitter is undefined

Answer (score 0):

EventEmitter is part of the NodeJS API, is not available for browsers.

EDIT:
In App.jsx you have a function called "handleChange", that function should do the same thing you are doing on "componenDidMount" but using the actual value of the Dropdown, you don't need to manually create events.

Hope it helps

Comment: oh, did you installed the dependency for that?

Comment: no anyway do you have a solution for my problem? or a new solution that doesn'nt include event emitters